# Visual C# Read Fonts From Custom Directory

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts

I can enumerate the installed fonts on the system by this code:

```
InstalledFontCollection ifc = new InstalledFontCollection();
foreach(FontFamily font in ifc.Families)
{
    if (font.IsStyleAvailable(FontStyle.Regular))
    {
        // Code
    }
}
```

But I want to read fonts from a custom directory. For instance I will create this folder structure.

> C:\MyFonts
>   C:\MyFonts\Handwriting
>   C:\MyFonts\Gothic
>   ..
>   ..

I will copy true type or open type font files to these folders according to its category.

And let say I want to enumerate fonts only in the C:\MyFonts\Gothic folder in my program. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a [PrivateFontCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y505zzfw.aspx).

Comment: Always a pleasure to be of assistance.